# Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path [...] - ReactNative

Tags: react-native, redux

I am building and ReactNative application with Redux and I ran into an issue that is giving me a headache. I am receiving the following error when trying to reset the state to initial state:

`Error: Invariant failed: A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path 'recievedData.data.stem.ControlMeasurementDefinition'.  This may cause incorrect behaviour. (https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#do-not-mutate-state)]`

I am setting the redux state during a process by adding elements to an array and when I try to reset it to its initial state [], it gives me the mentioned error. I am using ReactNative with Expo and the error does not prevent the app from working correctly when testing the app directly through ExpoGo. However, when I instal an APK file and run it, the app gets stuck at a splash screen.

Thanks in advance for the help.

EDIT:

Here are the code snaps...

```js
const initialState = {
  data: {}
};

// reducer

const recievedDataReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_RECIEVED_DATA:
      return {
        ...state,
        data: action.payload,
      };
    case RESET_RECIEVED_DATA:
      return initialState;
    default:
      return {
        ...state
      };
  }
}
```

```js
// actions

export const setRecievedData = (data) => ({
  type: SET_RECIEVED_DATA,
  payload: data
});

export const resetRecievedData = () => ({
  type: RESET_RECIEVED_DATA,
  payload: []
})
```

State is being updated with `setRecievedData` and this action is being called every time the state changes. The only time I use `resetRecievedData` is when I want to reset the state. This is where I recieve the error.

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to manipulate the state and the reducer?

Answer (score 0):

1. You send a payload you don't process (you can remove payload here)

```js
export const resetRecievedData = () => ({
  type: RESET_RECIEVED_DATA,
  payload: [] // Can be removed
})
```

2. In data initial state is an object and not an array:

```js
const initialState = {
  data: {} // Replace {} with []
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, it didn't change much. Still getting the same error.